# Avatar reverted back after uploading a new one

Tags: support, profile-page, profile-picture

I uploaded an avatar to use with my account, but it was gone the next time I logged in and I was back to a default avatar.  What happened to the one I uploaded?  How do I reload it?

Comment: What was your avatar? Can you please upload it as image or at least describe it?

Comment: The best place to ask is on [your own meta](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1181) first.

Comment: There's no record of your profile picture having been changed from the original you had when you registered. Are you sure you *saved* it after uploading it? The big button at the bottom needs to be clicked afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

You might have forgotten to save it using the buttons at the bottom of the page. One is for saving it for the site you uploaded it on, one is for copying it to all your communities.

I've been there :)

Comment: How do I reload it?

Comment: re-upload it and save it